# how to import large json file into mongodb using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import the large data set json file into mongodb using mongoimport.

```
mongoimport --db test --collection sam1 --file 1234.json --jsonArray

error:
2014-07-02T15:57:16.406+0530 error: object to insert too large
2014-07-02T15:57:16.406+0530 tried to import 1 objects
```

Comment: What's your file look like?

Comment: Mongo has a 16Mb limit for a single JSON doc. You've likely got too much data. (Or shouldn't be using --jsonArray.)

Comment: my json file size 17MB. inside single document is occupied >16MB of data. How I can parse this data other than mongoimport( cos i am already facing issue with mongoimport).

Comment: If you have JSON documents larger than 16MB, you'll need to refactor those into smaller documents. The [maximum document size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit) limit is imposed by the MongoDB server, not `mongoimport`. As noted in an earlier comment, you probably shouldn't be using `--jsonArray` as the limit for the array is 16MB; splitting that into one line per array element may fix your import issue.

Comment: @MoreThanFive do you know how to do it. please check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034785/java-how-to-save-csv-file-which-has-100k-entries-using-gridfs-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment54006977_33034785

Comment: @MoreThanFive :  no luck yet

Answer (score 13):

Please try add this option: --batchSize 1

Like:

`mongoimport --db test --collection sam1 --file 1234.json --batchSize 1`

Data will be  parsed and stored into the database batchwise